# file.copy, loadworkbook not working in R shiny reactive environment but working outside reactive environment

Tags: r, shiny, download, readxl, openxlsx

I have created the following app to read an excel file from the temp folder in R. I would like to retain the file format in R shiny

```
library(XLConnect)
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(   
titlePanel("Writer App"),
sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Read File Here", accept = c(".xlsx")), downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")), mainPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table1"))))



server <- function(input, output) {
datasetInput <- reactive({
infile<- input$file
if (is.null(infile))
  return(NULL)    
#READ .XLSX AND .CSV FILES
if(grepl(infile, pattern = ".xlsx" )==T){data=read_excel(infile$datapath)} else 
if(grepl(infile , pattern = ".csv" )==T){data=read.csv(infile$datapath )}

#RENAME DATAFRAME WITH UNDERSCORES
names(data)<-gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "_", x =  names(data))
return(data) })
output$table1 <- renderDataTable({     
return(datasetInput())})


 output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  filename = function() {
  paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx", sep="")},
  content = function(file) {
  tf<-tempdir()
  Files=list.files(path=tf, pattern=".xlsx", recursive = TRUE)[1]       
  file.copy(from =paste0(tf, "/",Files ), to= "temp_1.xlsx")     
  wb2 <- loadWorkbook(file = "temp_1.xlsx")
  df_1<-data.frame("DF"= c(1:3))      
  addWorksheet(wb = wb2,sheetName =  "Parameters1")
  writeData(wb2, "Parameters1", df_1, startCol = 1, startRow = 2, rowNames = TRUE)
  saveWorkbook(wb2, file)})
  }

 shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

The Download button(output$downloadData) has a command to copy the file including the format from a temporary location to a new file temp.xlsx. this file is next loaded as workbook. a New sheet Parameters1 is added to the workbook wb2. Next, data frame(df_1) is written to sheet Parameters1 and the file is downloaded.

Now, the code within the output$downloadData works in the R console but doesnt work in the reactive environment of R shiny.

There seems to be an error in loadworkbook command. I am able to get the file by means of read_excel and then inserting the data. That however doesnt prserve the format of the loaded excel sheet. I request someone to guide me in this.

Comment: Which file is this that you are reading? `Files=list.files(path=tf, pattern=".xlsx", recursive = TRUE)[1] ` Is it the same excel file that the user uploads ?

Comment: yes. it is the same file. But it is stored in a temporary folder by shiny for reasons of data security. The wb2 object gets created. apparently the issue is with save function. thats where the issue appears to be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me without any error.

```
library(shiny)
library(openxlsx)
library(readxl)

ui <- fluidPage(   
  titlePanel("Writer App"),
  sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Read File Here", accept = c(".xlsx")), downloadLink("downloadData", "Download")), 
                mainPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table1"))))



server <- function(input, output) {
  datasetInput <- reactive({
    infile<- input$file
    if (is.null(infile))
      return(NULL)   
    #READ .XLSX AND .CSV FILES
    if(grepl(infile$datapath, pattern = ".xlsx" )){data=read_excel(infile$datapath)} else 
      if(grepl(infile$datapath , pattern = ".csv" )){data=read.csv(infile$datapath )}
    
    #RENAME DATAFRAME WITH UNDERSCORES
    names(data)<-gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "_", x =  names(data))
    return(data) 
})
  
  output$table1 <- renderDataTable({     
    return(datasetInput())})
  
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".xlsx", sep="")},
    content = function(file) {
      tf<-tempdir()
      Files=list.files(path=tf, pattern=".xlsx", recursive = TRUE)[1]    
      file.copy(from =paste0(tf, "/",Files ), to= "temp_1.xlsx")     
      wb2 <- loadWorkbook(file = "temp_1.xlsx")
      df_1<-data.frame("DF"= c(1:3))      
      addWorksheet(wb = wb2,sheetName =  "Parameters1")
      writeData(wb2, "Parameters1", df_1, startCol = 1, startRow = 2, rowNames = TRUE)
      saveWorkbook(wb2, file)
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Sir, have yo made any edits. Am unable to spot them.

Comment: I get this error" Warning: Error in [[: subscript out of bounds
  [No stack trace available]"

Comment: It may be a version issue. will reinstall R and my packages and check

Answer (score 0):

The issue is solved with the use of xlconnect package. Here is the code I employed

```
library(XLConnect)
library(shiny)
library(readxl)

 ui <- fluidPage(   
 titlePanel("Writer App"),
 sidebarLayout(sidebarPanel(fileInput(inputId = "file", label = "Read File 
 Here", accept =c(".xlsx")), downloadButton("downloadData", "Download")),                  
 mainPanel(dataTableOutput(outputId = "table1"))))

 server <- function(input, output) {
 datasetInput <- reactive({
 infile<- input$file
 if (is.null(infile))
  return(NULL)    
#READ .XLSX AND .CSV FILES
if(grepl(infile, pattern = ".xlsx" )==T){
  data=read_excel(infile$datapath)
} else if(grepl(infile , pattern = ".csv" )==T)
{data=read.csv(infile$datapath )}

#RENAME DATAFRAME WITH UNDERSCORES
names(data)<-gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "_", x =  names(data))
return(data) })
output$table1 <- renderDataTable({     
return(datasetInput())})
 output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
 filename = function() {
  "file.xlsx"},
content = function(file) {
wdf<-getwd()      
tf<-tempdir()      
Files=list.files(path=tf, pattern=".xlsx", recursive = TRUE)[1]
newWB <- loadWorkbook(filename=paste0(tf,"/",Files),create=TRUE)
createSheet(object = newWB,name='Parameters')
writeWorksheet(newWB,data=data.frame("X"=c(1:10),"Y"= 
c(1:10)),sheet='Parameters',header=TRUE,rownames=NULL)
saveWorkbook(object = newWB, file = file)})
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Note: I have commented openxlsx to avoid incompatibility between openxlsx and xlconnect. Another change involves the removal of xlsx package as this is also incompatible with xlconnect